# video player issue on ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop pc

Tags: usb

How can i install vlc media player or other softwares on my pc in which have installed the ubuntu 16.04.
In windows and other os, we can see the video player softwares are installed in default. But in ubuntu that cannot be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Ubuntu software center by clicking its icon in launcher and you will find all types of softwares including vlc.